# Running schema.sql and seed.sql in my Dockerfile based on the mysql image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to change my docker-compose to instead of running mysql from the iamge, create my own Dockerfile for mysql so I can run my schema.sql and seed.sql when the mysql container loads.

You can see I commented out the "`image`" in the mysql section and added the `"build:./mysql"` attribute.

```
version: "2"

services:
  web:
    build: "."
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "3000:3000"

  mysql:
    build: './mysql'
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    #image: "mysql:5.7"
    volumes:
      - "mysql:/var/lib/mysql"

volumes:
  mysql: {}
```

I want to create a Dockerfile that is just like this image:

```
mysql/5.7
```

The image is found here: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/tree/mysql-server/5.7

I want to then run 2 scripts when the image loads:

```
schema.sql
```

and

```
seed.sql
```

I tried this so far:

**/mysql/Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql/5.7
```

When I run my docker-compose up --build

I get this error:

```
Building mysql
Step 1/1 : FROM mysql/5.7
ERROR: Service 'mysql' failed to build: pull access denied for mysql/5.7, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

How can I run the schema.sql and seed.sql commands?
Do I really need to login to get this image?  it works when I just use the  image attribute but it is asking to login when I create a seperate Dockerfile for mysql.